# How to force install packages on the fly re-try a install?

Tags: errors, installing-fonts

I was trying to compile a TeX file for the very first time.  In turns out, fonts I use are not included in the vanilla copy of MikTeX 2.9, and trying to compile my TeX file redirected to install the package for it on the fly.  It turned out my disk was full, so the installation failed.  Now, it just sees that that package failed to install, and does not try to install it again.

I tried re-copying all the files from a vanilla copy of MikTex 2.9, but that did not make the install-packages-on-the-fly come back.
How can I make the MikTeX try to install this package again?

I am running this in Windows.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall this package using the MikTeX package manager (or install it from there)?

Comment: Problem is, I don't remember what package it was.  Will the package manager tell me which packages failed to install?

Comment: Which fonts do you want to use?

Comment: @Bernard It looks like `eufm7` is the only one prevening the PDF from being created.

Comment: I suppose you mean `eurm7`, the Euler fonts?

Comment: @Bernard No, it says the following:
`Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason:

  The eufm source file could not be found.`, and then `Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason:

  PK font eufm7 could not be created.`

Comment: Seems like `eufm7` belongs to the `amsfonts` package.

Comment: OK. It's in the Euler family. Did you install the `amsfonts` package?

Comment: I think it's just the standard math-mode font, when the headers are: `\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}`. Here is the command that is run in the background to try to create this font: `E:\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\miktex-makepk.exe --verbose eufm7 514 600 0+514/600`

Comment: It is trying to make bitmap fonts, instead of using the type 1 fonts. This means it doesn't find the latter. Try running  from the command line `-updmap --verbose`  (the switch is to see what happens), and recompile.

Comment: @Bernard Package manager said `amsfonts` is installed.  I removed it (618 files), reinstalled it (619 files), and now everything works.  Thanks!  Though for future reference, I assume you meant those as switches to the `miktex-makepk.exe`, correct?

Comment: Non. You shouldn't even see mentioning `makepk` in the .log file. The problem is that the type 1 fonts database has to be refreshed (it's the files `dvipd.map` and friends). It isn't done at installation so you have to run this command  yourself (maybe as administrator).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks-- I'll try to find some resources to read about type 1 fonts, so that in the future I can know what's going on, and don't have to ask on here.

Comment: Oh! In practice, it's very simple: when a font is installed and you see a message mentionin `makepk` at compiation, it means it's not mentioned and the type 1 font databases, and you have to run `updmap` to do it.

Comment: @Bernard If you recall, the way I fixed this problem was, by removing amsfonts and re-installing it. When I move these (working) files to a new location, the same error occurs. Running those files from the old location works without a problem. Also, running `updmap` does fix the problem-- which I do not mind doing every time I move the files.  Do you have an idea, though, what might be causing this? p.s., you are welcome to post an answer, so that I can mark it as the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: @Alex: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem. What are these ‘working files’? The files on which you're working, or the font files from the distribution? If you mean the former, the databases `psfonts.map` and the like should mention the location of the type1 fonts for everyone. Did you run `updmap --admin`?

Comment: @Bernard By "(working) files" I meant the directory with the entire (portable) distribution on MikTex.  When I copy this directory to another location (e.g. from a USB to the computer), then I have to re-run `updmap`from the new location.  No `--admin` necessary.